# Is ARToolKit installer not available Windows now?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, artoolkit, android-augmented-reality

I am developing an augmented reality based mobile application on Windows that is based on foot detection. I want to develop this application using ARToolKit. The documentation at https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit5 says 'Run the ARToolKit installer executable', but I cannot find any installer exe file there. When I open http://artoolkit.org/download-artoolkit-sdk to access installer as suggested on http://daslhub.org/unlv/wiki/doku.php?id=nxt_ar_toolkit, it redirects me to www.daqri.com. There is no download link at this site for ARToolKit. Can anyone help me finding a Windows installer for ARToolKit or at least guide me to some other alternatives that can provide NFT based marker support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get artoolkitX binaries for Windows from http://www.artoolkitx.org/docs/downloads/ packed as a zip. If you are after ARToolKit5 there is a zipped version available here: https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkit5/releases

I would recommend artoolkitX because it is newer and supports 2D trackables (JPEG) as trackable on Windows.

You can read documentation here: https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkitx/wiki

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out. One thing that I want to know is that is artoolkitX built upon ARToolKit? And does it provide all the functionalities that are supported by ARToolKit? I am after a solution that provides NFT Tracking for my project that will use human foot as a marker.

Comment: Yes nft tracker is in there too. ArtoolkitX is done by the same team. Newer better and same features. Just read on the website. But I’m somehow sure you want 2D tracker way better than the nft thing.

Comment: Well, that's great to hear. I need to place augmented shoes on users' feet, therefore don't you think NFT will be used for this purpose?